# laravel model event from trait not firing

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

why this is not working?? anything else i need to doo??? (note: i don't want to call any `boot` method from `model`). in models its working fine with `booted` method

```php
// route
Route::get('/tests', function () {

    return Test::find(1)->update([
        'name' => Str::random(6)
    ]);
});

// models
namespace App\Models;

use App\Http\Traits\Sortable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Sortable;
    protected $guarded = ["id"];
}

// traits
namespace App\Http\Traits;

trait Sortable
{

    protected static function bootSort()
    {
        static::updated(function ($model) {
            dd("updated", $model->toArray());
        });
        static::updating(function ($model) {
            dd("updating", $model->toArray());
        });
        static::saving(function ($model) {
            dd("saving", $model->toArray());
        });
        static::saved(function ($model) {
            dd("saved", $model->toArray());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `bootSort` and why would the framework call that automatically? I've never used the boot methods from a trait but at the very least you need to follow naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer if I want to fire model event from trait: I have to make the boot method name as trait class name with prefix `boot`

for example: if my trait name is `Sortable` the boot method name will be `bootSortable`
below is the full solution to question:

```php
// route
Route::get('/tests', function () {

    return Test::find(1)->update([
        'name' => Str::random(6)
    ]);
});

// models
namespace App\Models;

use App\Http\Traits\Sortable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Sortable;
    protected $guarded = ["id"];
}

// traits
namespace App\Http\Traits;

trait Sortable
{
    // before
    protected static function bootSort()
    // after fix
    protected static function bootSortable()
    {
        static::updated(function ($model) {
            dd("updated", $model->toArray());
        });
        static::updating(function ($model) {
            dd("updating", $model->toArray());
        });
        static::saving(function ($model) {
            dd("saving", $model->toArray());
        });
        static::saved(function ($model) {
            dd("saved", $model->toArray());
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [laravel observers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#observers), it's much more simpler

Comment: yes I can but I have to create the observer class for each model but with trait, I can use with multiple models

Comment: you can have one observer and use it across your models